# Nancy: how do I capture all requests irrespective of verb or path

Tags: c#, nancy

I want to use Nancy with the default routing, as it's clean and works well, however I want an option to log all incoming requests to the console (I'm using Nancy's self-hosting module) irrespective of whether an explicit route exists. Put simply, I want to be able to capture the verb, the incoming request URI, any posted data (if it's a POST request), etc.

How do I do this? `Before`/`After` only seem to run for requests that match an existing route, and a 404 does not trigger `OnError` either. Also, using `Get["/(.*)"]` only catches GET requests and will ignore other HTTP verbs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `Before`/`After` on an Application level, not Module, for that https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/The-Application-Before%2C-After-and-OnError-pipelines