# How to Intercept all Nancy requests

Tags: nancy

I have seen this post: [Nancy: how do I capture all requests irrespective of verb or path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591494/nancy-how-do-i-capture-all-requests-irrespective-of-verb-or-path) and followed along on the github article.

But it does not work.  I have simply added a class in my project:

```
 public class MyBootstrapper : Nancy.DefaultNancyBootstrapper
```

But this class is never instantiated, and the github documentation does not discuss this in any detail.

What do I need to do to cause my bootstrapper to be used?

Answer (score 3):

I found it.  There are two ways to add items to the pipeline.  One by deriving a Bootstrap class, which failed for me.  The other by implementing a class which honored the IApplicationStartup interface.  That worked, and here is the code:

```
  public class BeforeAllRequests : IApplicationStartup
{
    public void Initialize(IPipelines pipelines)
    {
        pipelines.BeforeRequest.AddItemToStartOfPipeline(ctx => {
            if (ctx != null)
            {
                Log.Debug("Request: " + ctx.Request.Url);
            }
            return null;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (4 years later, maybe the Wiki changed since then):  [Bootstrapper](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Bootstrapper)