# How can I do something before processing a request in Nancy 2.x?

Tags: nancy

I want to do some things in every request, no matter the Module or Route. How can I accomplish this in Nancy 2.x?

If found [How to Intercept all Nancy requests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34823373) and [How do I capture all requests irrespective of verb or path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17591494), but they are only applicable for Nancy 1.x and the [Documentation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki) is out-of-date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say documentation is not updated and most of the resources you can find online are for version 1.x.

How to solve it depends a little bit on what you want to do. If you are not messing with the response you can override `ApplicationStartUp` in the bootstrapper like this:

```cs
protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
{
    pipelines.BeforeRequest.AddItemToEndOfPipeline((ctx) =>
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Hit");
        return null;
    });
    base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);
}
```

If you, on the other hand, need to meddle with the response and the headers you can do it in the constructor of your overridden `NancyModule` with your `Get` setup like this:

```cs
public InstrumentProgrammingNancyModule()
{
    //// Enable CORS. 
    After.AddItemToEndOfPipeline((ctx) =>
        {
            ctx.Response.WithHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*") 
                .WithHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET"); 
        });

    Get("/" , _ =>
    {
        return somethingOrOther;
    });
    ....
}
```

Both of these solutions work with Nancy 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
 public class NewBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
 {
        protected override void RequestStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines, NancyContext context)
        {
            //Your code here
            base.RequestStartup(container, pipelines, context);
        }
 }
```

Comment: Hi, I would really like an explanation of what does this snippet of code does, as copy pasting this snippet does not helps me to understand what is doing and how can I improve it.

Comment: Nancy offers hooks and there are two ways you can hook in to the request pipeline. Overriding the bootstrapper like I showed above is one of them. I prefer this way because it gives access to the ioc container and the http request so you can do lots of things in there.